# Flutter: Barcode and TextField actions

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode

im using a BarCode Scanner Terminal.

When Im Scanning the BarCode, Code automatically is written in the TextField.

I have a button that is saving data and displaying it below, but I want to remove the button and somehow make a check **if Textfield is not empty or If I paste a code then do the following action ...** (display data below as example). So every time I change data, it makes the action **without PRESSING BUTTON**

Any ideas how to do this or help will help me a lot, thanks.

[image: Example of app]

Answer (score 1):

when you will enter even a word your test will be shown under the textfield.[image: Look this code]

Answer (score 0):

You can save text in list when text is changed in TextFormField

```
List<String> strList =[];

 TextFormField(
     onChanged: (str){
     if(str.isNotEmpty)
        strList.add(str);
   },
 ),
```

It can help you

Comment: Thanks, great idea, but I also need somehow to detect that there is data without pressing any button

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have a controller for your TextField, so you can check if the controller is empty or not, and you can do like this:

```
yourcontroller.text.isEmpty? Container() : YourButton(),
```